# How to put MouseArea inside buildings boundaries in QML Map

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to make buildings on map clickable using MouseArea. I tried using GeocodeModel with query "building" which was obviously stupid idea. Then I tried getting mapItems : list of Map Object and printing them on the console, but that: "qml: Map items: []" was the only result. Now I'm thinking if it is even possible without going into implementation side of maybe delegate of Map if such thing exists :P Why there is nothing in mapItems ? Are they in some way private in Map ?

My shortened code:

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480   

Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin{
        name: "osm"
    }
    zoomLevel: 15

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Map items:  ", map.mapItems);
    }
}

GeocodeModel{
    id: geoModel
    plugin: Plugin{
        name: "osm"
    }
    autoUpdate: true
    query: "building"
    limit: -1

    onLocationsChanged: {
        map.center = geoModel.get(0).coordinate
        console.log(count);
    }

}
```

Comment: You must show what you have tried. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I tried using GeocodeModel with query "building" which was obviously stupid idea. I tried getting mapItems : list<MapItem> of Map Object and printing them on the console, but that: "qml: Map items:   []" was the only result. Now I'm thinkig if it is even possible without going into implementation side of maybe delegate of Map if such thing exists :P

Comment: I recommend you read the following to improve your question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)